# What to enter for Homepage and Privacy Policy link for google oauth 2.0 app verification

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth, verification

I have created a google application and want to use the youtube api to get some information about my private playlist using python. The problem is that I need to use a sensitive scope:  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly. So, now need to verify my google application and enter some information in Oauth consent screen but I don't know what to enter in homepage link or privacy policy link or Domain authorization.

I went to read the information on "Unverified Apps" and it told me to include the privacy policy and homepage link (with Terms of Service ?) and it said that I needed to verify my domain (???)

> Before you start the verification process, review the OAuth Application Verification FAQ. This will help your verification process go quickly. To start the verification process for apps, do the following steps:
> Update the OAuth consent screen details in the Google Cloud Platform Console APIs & Services Credentials:
> You must have a privacy policy URL.
> Add URLs for your homepage and Terms of Service if you have them.
> Verify your website ownership through Search Console by using an account that is a Project Owner or a Project Editor on your OAuth project.
> The same account must be a verified owner of the property in Search Console. For more information about Search Console permissions, see Managing owners, users, and permissions.
> We can't approve your OAuth verification request until your site ownership verification is complete. For more information, see Verify your site ownership.

I just want to get some information from my account so I really don't know what to do?

**So I'm wondering what to put in Homepage link, Private Policy link, Domain Authorization and for the Domain Verification Or if everything that I'm doing is wrong???**
**Thanks**

Comment: Hi,

I've got the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but I found out that I could just click on "advance Configuration" then I clicked on " Go to **Name of API** (Not secure)". And it worked!